# Unit Analysis Question: Possible to Solve

Tags: homework-and-exercises, units, dimensional-analysis

*A nautical mile is the distance traveled in moving through one minute of latitude. A ship which is sailing at a speed of five knots travels five nautical miles in one hour. Two hundred years ago, the speed of a British naval vessel was determined by lowering a small sea anchor which was called a log, and then measuring the length of cable played out from the ship during a fixed period of time. The length of cable was measured in fathoms (one fathom equals six feet) and every eight fathoms a knot was placed in the cable. The speed might thus be recorded as “three knots, two fathoms”. The measuring period was determined using a small sand-filled “hour” glass. What was the length of time used for the measurement? (1 foot = 305 mm)*

I do not understand how we are suppose to isolate for the variable of time... all they have given is a process. Also is a nautical mile relative? What is travelling at what speed through one minute of latitude. This does not make sense to me.

Comment: In the context of latitude, [minute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minute_and_second_of_arc) is a unit of angle, not time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, a *minute* doesn’t mean 1/60 of an hour, it means 1/60 of a degree.

A minute of latitude is 1/21,600 of a complete  circuit around the Earth.